# What is that symbol standing for?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, computational-complexity

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.02382.pdf

Page 30 Lemma 7.6, there is written something like $O_P(\cdot)$ - it looks like the Landau notation, that the right term doesn't grow faster than $c \cdot \sqrt{\frac{log(d)}{T}}$ for some constant $c$.

But is this what is meant here? What is the $P$ standing for?

Comment: And $P$ is a variable or the probability?

Comment: @yanko I am sorry but your explanation doesn't look based on a firm ground.

Comment: I would bet on [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation) (Big O: stochastic boundedness). Note the $o_P()$ (little O) version appearing in Lemma 7.4.

Comment: Here is "Big O in probability" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation